# TextView.text is cut mid width inside TableLayout TableRow

Tags: xml, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Main issue: text is squished so hard by View, so it gets cut.
Key moments:

1. TableRow is a child of LinearLayout so weight is supported.
2. TableRow contains one `TextView` with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` other are `"0dp"`
3. All TableRow child views have `android:weight="1"`
4. TableLayout android:isScrollContainer="true" is present

**Text cut issue photo**
[image]

full code here:
https://gist.github.com/Sukhobrusov/af5608c520056e114743215eca1631f0

1. android:isScrollContainer="true"
2. TextView.android:layout_gravity="fill"
3. Placing everything inside HorizontalScrollView won't work, as width is not working "0dp"
4. `view hierarchy`:

```
Table
- Row
- - Text wrap_content
- - Text 0dp
- - Text 0dp
.
.
~
```

Expected behaviour: View is squished to the limit until it's impossible to surpass the minWidth = 1 symbol. WRAP_CONTENT TextView shouldn't push more as the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
It's impossible to stretch the TableLayout from XML the way I wanted to.
So the answer will be to just set the `android:layout_width` to some number and REMOVE THE WEIGHTS

```
Table
- Row
- - Text wrap_content
- - Text 10dp
- - Text 10dp
```

Comment: some simmilar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638862/why-does-android-layout-weight-and-wrap-content-give-more-space-than-needed